# Magento 2 Fatal Error when running composer:install

Tags: magento2, laminas-dependency-plugin

1. Clone fresh Magento 2 instance;
   2.Run composer:install

Fatal Error:
[PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined class constant 'PRE_COMMAND_RUN'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/riWLl.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was an issue with Composer, By installing latest version of Composer solved it.
[The bug](https://github.com/composer/composer/commit/b1bfb9bb65641d35434209c2c60169a92e99d1e3) for the constant variable PRE_COMMAND_RUN is raised and closed.

Comment: Thanks mate, you just saved our deployment

Comment: How to solve this problem. I have installed today and I am facing this problem

Answer (score 4):

**You need install latest version of composer, upgrade steps given below.**

-- Remove existing composer

Debian/Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get remove composer
```

Centos/Redhat

```
sudo yum remove composer
```

Get the latest composer using wget.

```
cd /tmp
sudo curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
```

Move composer executable to PATH so it can be accessible globally.

```
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

To check the composer version

```
composer -V
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to reinstall the Composer and use the latest composer version

To do that you can follow the following steps:

**Step #1**) Remove the current composer:

```
sudo apt-get remove composer
```

**Step #2**) install the composer , you can using following commands

```
php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === 'e0012edf3e80b6978849f5eff0d4b4e4c79ff1609dd1e613307e16318854d24ae64f26d17af3ef0bf7cfb710ca74755a') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
php composer-setup.php
php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

then to make sure you have the latest Composer , run the following command

```
php composer.phar -V
```

Now, your ready to install Magento,
to install Magento via composer :

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition YourProjectName
```

if the project folder name is exist , remove the folder and try again to install magento

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an outdated version that doesn't even support self-update unfortunately.
So here's a oneliner to install the latest version in /usr/local/bin:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | sudo php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Check:

```
which -a composer
/usr/local/bin/composer --version
composer --version
```

Answer (score 0):

Composer self-update wasnt working with my composer version, I use ubuntu(LEMP).
Latest version of composer was installed - 1.6.3 I think.

We need this 1.10.17.

```
    sudo apt remove compsoer
    php -r "copy('https://getcomposer.org/installer', 'composer-setup.php');"
    php -r "if (hash_file('sha384', 'composer-setup.php') === '756890a4488ce9024fc62c56153228907f1545c228516cbf63f885e036d37e9a59d27d63f46af1d4d07ee0f76181c7d3') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); } echo PHP_EOL;"
    sudo php composer-setup.php --version=1.10.17 --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer
```

Check version:

```
composer --version
 
output: 1.10.17
```

To be sure remove all vendor and cache:

```
rm -rf vendor/*
composer clear-cache
composer update
```